# preg_match_all doesn't find anything

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I'm trying to match the following string `<a href="\"http://localhost/innovare-kh/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/CouncilTax.pdf\"">CouncilTax</a>` with `preg_match_all()` but I keep receiving NULL. I have tested it [on this website](http://www.phpliveregex.com/). This is how I use the function:

`preg_match_all('/(?<=href=\")(.*?\.(.*?))\\/', $description, $out)`

Where description is the above string and $out is just an empty variable.

Thanks,
Nevo

Comment: Enable `error_reporting(E_ALL);` to be notified of your syntax woe.

Comment: is the input string is an exact string?

Comment: The link in the string will vary, but the rest will be the same.

Comment: @mario, it says no ending delimiter found.. weird. Do you see any error with the regex I've written?

Comment: @Nevos try with a different delimiter `preg_match_all('~(?<=href=\")(.*?\.(.*?))\\~', $description, $out)`

Comment: The backslash needs more escaping ``\\\\`` to pass the string and become a literal character in the regex.

Comment: There is no ending delimiter found, because you masked/escaped it: \\/ first backslash escapes the second in regard to PHP text literal syntax, so you end up with \/ in your actual regular expression, and in that context now the backslash masks the slash.

Comment: @CBroe and @mario, OK, thanks. Now I've changed it to `(?<=href=\"\\\")(.*?\.(.*?))` but it still doesn't work precisely as needed. I want to get the link out of the string, as well as the format of the file (in this case 'pdf'. Can anyone help me write the correct regex for it?

Comment: @Nevos could you post the exact string without escaping the double quotes?

Comment: That's the exact string...

Answer (score 0):

You need 3 consecutives backslashes:

```
$description = '<a href="\"http://localhost/innovare-kh/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/CouncilTax.pdf\"">CouncilTax</a>';
preg_match_all('/(?<=href=\")(.*?\.(.*?))\\\/', $description, $out);
print_r($out);
```

**output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => \"http://localhost/innovare-kh/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/CouncilTax.pdf\
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => \"http://localhost/innovare-kh/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/CouncilTax.pdf
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => pdf
        )

)
```